# trouble initializing jqTouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtouch

I'm trying to add a swipe animation to an element. I've tried initializing jqTouch before the `ready` handler like this:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
    slideSelector:'#navMenu'
});

$(document).ready(function () {
//...
});
```

But I am getting a `TypeError` saying that `$.jqTouch` is undefined. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: It might help if you posted some more of the code (from a web document, I assume). It's possible the problem lies in a missing script (check Web Inspector/Firebug), or bad syntax somewhere outside the JS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQTouch with jQuery, you now need to include two library files: the jQTouch library, and then the jQTouch jQuery bridge file, which essentially bridges jQTouch to use jQuery instead of the default it ships for, Zepto.js.

I always find it funny that the library that is named after (or in the style of) a library, now needs a shim in order to work with jQuery :)

Comment: @Mattygabe--that is indeed strange.